# ODE Cauchy problem

Tags: differential-equations

I want to prove that the followning Cauchy problem doesn't have solution:

$y'(x)\sin(x)=y\ln(y),y(\frac{\pi}{2})=1$

I solved the ODE and i found:

$\ln(|\ln(y)|)=\ln(|\tan(\frac{x}{2})|)+c$

When i put the initial condition, i found ln(0).
How do i prove, that this problem doesn't have solution?

Comment: This site is about the software Mathematica, your question seem to be about the mathematics, You should ask your question here: https://math.stackexchange.com/ probably...

Answer (score 1):

The general solution is

```
Y = DSolveValue[{y'[x] Sin[x] == y[x] Log[y[x]]  }, y, x,GeneratedParameters -> k]    
(*Function[{x}, E^(E^k[1] Tan[x/2])]*)
```

Plot shows

```
Plot[ {Y[Pi/2 ], 1}, {k[1], -1, 1}, PlotRange -> {0, Automatic}]
```

[image]

that `Y[Pi/2]>1`! The boundary condition `Y[Pi/2]==1` can't be satisfied, the solution doesn't exist in this case!

The mathematical prove  follows via `Limit[Y[Pi/2],k[1]->-Infinity] (*1*)` and `Y'[x]>0]`